# How can i get dropdown list after i enter @ in input field?

Tags: javascript

How to get drop-down list after i enter @ in input field?

For example:- When you enter @ in whatsapp group we will get drop-down list of all people in that group.

how can i achieve the same in javascript ?

Comment: Please provide you code.

Comment: maybe you could look at jquery combobox :                          http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the input is an "@" character and append a select tag to the body.

```js
function checkForAt() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

  if (typeof document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0] === "undefined") {

    if (input == "@") {
      var select = document.createElement('select');
      document.body.appendChild(select);

      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.innerText = "some stuff";
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="input" id="input" onkeyup="checkForAt()">
```